# create member variable of type that contains atomic value as its member

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm using a third-party library with a class containing `atomic<double>`. Now the library returns a reference to that class object while calling a function. Now I want to keep that reference somewhere to reuse it in my application workflow.

[Here is the actual class from the third party lib](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp/blob/master/core/include/prometheus/gauge.h#L24)
[Here is the function that returns the reference](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp/blob/master/core/include/prometheus/family.h#L111)

Since it holds the atomic value I can't copy the class object (`Gauge` in the above link) and also I can't change that third party library at the moment. Is there any workaround for this?

I have tried to store the returned reference value in a `unique_ptr<Gauge>`

```
std::unique_ptr<prometheus::Gauge> cpuUsageInPercent = std::make_unique<prometheus::Gauge>(
            prometheus::BuildGauge()
                    .Name("cpu_usage_percent")
                    .Help("cpu usage in percent")
                    .Register(*m_registry)
                    .Add({}));
```

but I got the below error

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/unique_ptr.h:962:30: error: use of deleted function ‘prometheus::Gauge::Gauge(const prometheus::Gauge&)’
  962 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
```

Comment: Since the variable is private *and* the library does not expose it, you should really not use it, and neither should you keep a reference to it.

Comment: @limserhane I edited my question. I don't want to copy the atomic value, I want to copy the class which contains the atomic value

Comment: And why can't you store a reference (or pointer, or `std::reference_wrapper`) to that `Gauge`?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want. If the function returns a reference to a `Gauge` object, why wouldn't you be able to keep that reference ?

Comment: @molbdnilo I updated the question again. Because I'm getting the error says that copy constructor is deleted

Comment: What do you mean by trying to store a reference in a `std::unique_ptr`? A `unique_ptr` has to be *unique* as the name implies, it cannot refer to an existing object elsewhere

Comment: @UnholySheep updated my question again. Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: `std::make_unique` creates a new object - since you pass a reference to a different object as argument it tries to copy it. Which is deleted because that object has an `std::atomic` member. And based on everything else you wrote you don't actually want to create an `std::unique_ptr` but instead either a "raw pointer" or a `std::reference_wrapper`. Smart pointers are not the tool to use here

Comment: @UnholySheep If I use std::reference_wrapper I need to initialize my member variable with some dummy value before I rebound it to the actual value by calling the function, isn't it?

Comment: If it is a member variable then yes in which case you might prefer to have a "regular" pointer member variable (which you initialize to a null pointer). An alternative would be a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper` - although that gets quite verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

How about writing this?

```
Gauge & g = prometheus::BuildGauge()
                    .Name("cpu_usage_percent")
                    .Help("cpu usage in percent")
                    .Register(*m_registry)
                    .Add({});
```

### Long Answer

If you have a function returning a reference, say

```
X &f();
```

then you can simply take the address of the result and store it, like so:

```
X * ptr = &f();
```

You can then refer to the object by pointer. You can copy the pointer around and thus keep it in the application wherever you want. You can also refer to the object by reference like this:

```
X & obj = f();
```

If you put something into an `std::unique_ptr<X>`, then this indicates that you become the unique *owner* of the object. However, you only want to *borrow* the reference as far as I can tell. Therefore, a simple raw pointer may be exactly what you need.

If you use `std::make_unique<X>()` to create an object, then you have to pass arguments to that function which are accepted as arguments to a constructor of `X`. The `Gauge` class does not provide a constructor which takes a `Gauge &` as argument.

Comment: @Vencat needs to keep the reference in class scope, so storing the reference is not an option here :'(